# Text-To-Speech Initialization Delay

Tags: android, text-to-speech, speech-to-text, google-text-to-speech

I am trying to add text-to-speech feature to my app, and it is working fine until I updated TTS from Google Play store.

There wasn't any delay to initialize the TTS in onCreate Method.
After the update, it would take 3-5 seconds for this TTS to finish initializing.
Basically, the text-to-speech is not ready until 3-5 seconds later.

Can someone please tell me what I've done wrong?

```
private HashMap<String, String> TTS_ID = new HashMap<String, String>(); 

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    .....

    .....

    TextToSpeech_Initialize();
}

public void TextToSpeech_Initialize() {
    TTS_ID.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "UniqueID");     
    speech = new TextToSpeech(MainActivity.this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
         @Override
         public void onInit(int status) {
            if(status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
               speech.setSpeechRate(SpeechRateValue);
               speech.speak(IntroSpeech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, TTS_ID);
           }
         }
    });

}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: `speak()` method will be operated after `onInit()` method is completed. Because, when you create a `TextToSpeech` instance, your app try to connect tts service in your system with `TextToSpeech.OnInitListener`. So i suggest to call `speak()` method after `onInit()` method is completely finished. Also, you should call `setLanguage()` before use `speak()` to select voice.

Comment: I've tried to run the speak(); after onInit() method is complete like you mentioned, but it's still giving me the same huge delay issues.  Thanks

Comment: Hmm.. What is the target API? Is it over API 21 or not?

Comment: Android 4.3 and Android 5.1.1.  It doesn't matter since it has to do with Google TTS update.  They added more languages to the update, but it screwed up by adding delay to the initialization.  It's so frustrating on how Google does their stuff compared to Apple!

Comment: It would appear this is an issue with the update. Check 'listen to a sample' in the TTS settings and see if it occurs there too.

Answer (score 3):

Confirmed! This is an issue with Google text to speech engine, if you try any other tts the delay disappears, eg Pico tts.

Answer (score -1):

I have stumbled across this problem before but now I have found a proper solution..

**You can initialize TextToSpeach in onCreate() like this:**

```
TextToSpeach textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
```

but first you need to *`implement TextToSpeech.OnInitListener`*, and then you need to override the `onInit()` method:

```
@Override
public void onInit(int status) {

    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Language not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            button.setEnabled(true);
        }

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Init failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I also noticed that if you didn't set the language in `onInit()` there is gonna be a delay!!

**And now you can write the method that says the text:**

```
private void speakOut(final String detectedText){
        if(textToSpeech !=null){
            textToSpeech.stop(); //stop and say the new word
            textToSpeech.speak(detectedText ,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
        }
    }
```